# Carousel View is scrolling me to the first item when I type in an Entry

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am creating a mobile android application where I use a carousel View and display data from a server, the user needs to type a data from a machine and verify if the data of the machine is the same as received by the server and save it.

I use data templates depending on the data received by the server and it works fine.

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Manual_Logger.Checklist"
             xmlns:viewmodels1="clr-namespace:Manual_Logger.ViewModel" xmlns:selector="clr-namespace:Manual_Logger.Control"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
             BackgroundColor="#E9ECEF">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels1:Tour_TagViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <!-- Parammeters Template-->

            <DataTemplate x:Key="parameterViewTemplate">
                <StackLayout x:Name="stackTest">
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#f8f9fa" HasShadow="True"
                                           BorderColor="DarkGray"
                                           CornerRadius="5"
                                           Margin="0"
                                           HeightRequest="350"
                                           WidthRequest="300"
                                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <ScrollView>
                            <StackLayout >

                                <!-- Insert Text if it is only text -->

                                <Label Text="Texto Esperado"
                                                   x:Name="txtEsperado"
                                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"/>


                                <!-- Display data -->
                                <Frame x:Name="frame" CornerRadius="5" Padding="2">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Parameter}"
                                                       x:Name="expectedValues"
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Frame >

                                <!-- Type data by user  -->

                                <Label Text="Valor:"
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

                                <Frame CornerRadius="5" Padding="0"  >
                                    <Entry   FontSize="Medium" 
                                                         WidthRequest="250" 
                                                         HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                                         HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                                         VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                         x:Name="entryPosicion"/>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <!-- Range Template -->

            <DataTemplate x:Key="rangeViewTemplate">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Frame BackgroundColor="#f8f9fa" HasShadow="True"
                                           BorderColor="DarkGray"
                                           CornerRadius="5"
                                           Margin="0"
                                           HeightRequest="350"
                                           WidthRequest="300"
                                           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <ScrollView>
                            <StackLayout>

                                <!--Insert if are numeric values-->

                                <Label Text="Valor Maximo Esperado"
                                                   
                                                   x:Name="txtValorMaximo"
                                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

                                <Frame  CornerRadius="5" Padding="2"  >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Tag_Name_Maximum_Expected}"
                                                               x:Name="showValorMaximo"
                                                       
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Frame>

                                <Label Text="Valor Minimo Esperado"
                                                   
                                                   x:Name="txtValorMinimo"
                                                   FontSize="Medium"
                                                   FontAttributes="Italic"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

                                <Frame  CornerRadius="5" Padding="2"  >
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Tag_Name_Minimum_Expected}"
                                                               x:Name="showValorMinimo"
                                                       
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Frame>

                                <!-- Type data by user  -->

                                <Label Text="Valor:"
                                                       FontSize="Medium"
                                                       FontAttributes="Italic"
                                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"/>

                                <Frame CornerRadius="5" Padding="0"  >
                                    <Entry   FontSize="Medium" 
                                             WidthRequest="250" 
                                             HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                             VerticalOptions="Center"x:Name="entryPosicion"/>
                                </Frame>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>

            <selector:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="mainTemplate"  ParameterTemplate="{StaticResource parameterViewTemplate}" RangeTemplate="{StaticResource  rangeViewTemplate}">
            </selector:MyDataTemplateSelector>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <StackLayout x:Name="parametersStack" Margin="0, 5 ,0,0">
        <Label Text="{Binding Tag_Name}" Margin="25, 20, 15, 0" FontSize="27" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
        <Frame CornerRadius="3" BackgroundColor="white" Margin="15, 5, 15, 30" Padding="5, 10 , 5 , 10">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="430"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <CarouselView IndicatorView="indicatorView" ItemsSource="{Binding Get_Tour_Run_Tags}"  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource mainTemplate}"   x:Name="lstData">
                    
                </CarouselView>
                <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" MaximumVisible="15" Margin="0,0,0,7"/>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class Checklist : ContentPage
{ 
    public Checklist()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Model:

```
*public class Tour_Tag
{
    public Guid Tour_Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Limit_Type
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Parameter
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string Tag_Name_Minimum_Expected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string Tag_Name_Maximum_Expected
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}*
```

ViewModel:

```
public class Tour_TagViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly IList<Tour_Tag> source;
    public ObservableCollection<Tour_Tag> Get_Tour_Run_Tags { get; private set; }

    public Tour_Tag CurrentItem { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }

    public Tour_TagViewModel()
    {
        source = new List<Tour_Tag>();
        CreateTourTagsCollection();

        CurrentItem = Get_Tour_Run_Tags.Skip(3).FirstOrDefault();
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
        Position = 3;
        OnPropertyChanged("Position");
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    void CreateTourTagsCollection()
    {
        // V = Parammeters, M = Range, F = Scann
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer", Parameter = "R-EP01982_X6-T" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.PCB Part Number", Parameter = "EP01982 + BP1" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Stencil ID", Parameter = "SE3258-AXN [Rack LF - 7]" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Board Lock Fixture", Parameter = "PINES(YAMAHA) ,SE2726-AXN [Gaveta B - 32]" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Stencil Clean Rate", Parameter = "5" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Solder Paste Number", Parameter = "250" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Squeegee Dimensions", Parameter = "ROH-LOCTITE" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "M", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Squeegee Speed", Tag_Name_Maximum_Expected = "100", Tag_Name_Minimum_Expected = "80" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "M", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Squeegee Contact Angle", Tag_Name_Maximum_Expected = "60", Tag_Name_Minimum_Expected = "50" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "M", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Squeegee Pressure", Tag_Name_Maximum_Expected = "120", Tag_Name_Minimum_Expected = "100" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Distance Separation", Parameter = "1" });
        source.Add(new Tour_Tag { Limit_Type = "V", Tag_Name = "L5 Paste Printer.Separation Speed", Parameter = "5" });

        Get_Tour_Run_Tags = new ObservableCollection<Tour_Tag>(source);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The problem here is that if I type in an entry, the carousel is scrolling me back to the first item.

What I want to do is to type in the entries of each item, so in that way I could type the data that I want and save it.

Sorry if it is a really dumb problem, but I'm new at this.

Here is an example to be clear.

[Suposse I have four items displayed in a carousel view where each item has an entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omd5i.png)

[If I type in the third entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsuzF.png)

[The carousel view scrolls me back to the first item.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibtXo.png)

Comment: you need to use data binding to bind a VM property to the Entry, just like you do with your labels

Comment: It stop appearing in other entries but it still not working well, when I write in other entry it sends me to the first entry.

Comment: you need to be more specific - are you saying that when you type in an Entry the carousel is scrolling back to the first item?  Or does it happen when you hit Return?

Comment: Yes when I type in an entry the carousel is scrolling back to the first item

Comment: I try to put a for to count each item but I don't have an idea on how to implement to it

Comment: Maybe learn more on data binding because it seems as though you need to learn some more deeper concepts. Another thing I would recommend is to give us a better explanation on what you exactly want us to do. It's currently hard, or even impossible for me personally to understand what you mean by your title. Try drawing us a diagram if you want. Your code is nice and well-structured  though.

Comment: I edited the question I hope it gets more clear what I mean

Comment: I got the same result, Here is running gif.https://imgur.com/a/RfeygMU. You can open an issue in github thread.https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues `CarouselView` is preview, it will make some odd issues.

Comment: Thanks, I would open the issue later, for now I would do it from code behind, that is the only solution I can think right know. However if I found a solution I would post it here

Comment: Ok, thanks for your sharing.

Comment: @pl4s1ic_Str4w any updates?